# Execute query stored in variable in a very specific way

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

Greetings, I have a problem as follows:
I have an SQL variable declared:

```
DECLARE @myVariable nvarchar(max)
```

a third party library set a value for this variable. To simplify, lets say that the value is as follows:

```
SET @myVariable = 'Select ROWGUID from MySampleTable'
```

Now, I want to execute the following query:

```
SELECT ROWGUID FROM myTable WHERE ROWGUID in (exec sp_executesql @myVariable )
```

However, the above statement does not work because it returns an error telling me that I can't execute stored procedure in that way. I made a workaround and this is what I wrote:

```
create table #temptable (ID uniqueidentifier null)
if(@myVariable is not null AND @myVariable !='') insert into #temptable exec  sp_executesql @myVariable 

SELECT ROWGUID FROM myTable WHERE ROWGUID in (select * from #temptable) 
DROP TABLE #temptable
```

This works fine.However I don't think it is a good idea to use temporary table. How can I achieve the same result without necessity of creating temporary tables?

**I am using SQL SERVER 2005**

**UPDATE
Please read what I've written where is the problem:**

> However, the above statement does not work because it returns an error telling me that I can't execute stored procedure in that way. I made a workaround and this is what I wrote:

Comment: I forgot to mention about it. I am using SQL Server 2005

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SQL Server 2005 or 2008, you could use a Common Table Expression instead of creating a temporary table.

[Common Table Expressions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766.aspx)

Your CTE should look like:

```
WITH Records (ROWGUID) AS ( 
    SELECT ROWGUID 
      FROM MySimpleTable 
)
```

Then you can simply use:

```
SELECT ROWGUID 
  FROM myTable 
 WHERE ROWGUID IN (SELECT ROWGUID 
                     FROM Records);
```

Which potentially means you can drop your Variable.

---

**EDIT**

Ok, so CTE is out of the question.  But, what about using a Table variable instead of creating a Temporary Table.

```
DECLARE @myVar nvarchar(max);

DECLARE @table TABLE
(
    ROWGUID uniqueidentifier
)

SET @myVar = 'SELECT ROWGUID FROM MySampleTable';

INSERT INTO @table
  EXEC sp_executesql @myVar;

SELECT ClientID
  FROM myTable
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT ClientID FROM @table);
```

Comment: I've tried to use it but it does not work:
DECLARE @MyVariable nvarchar(max)
SET @MyVariable = 'SELECT ROWGUID FROM MySimpleTable
WITH Records (ROWGUID) AS (exec sp_executesql @MyVariable )
SELECT ROWGUID FROM myTable WHERE ROWGUID in (Records)

Comment: but how can I execute the statement exec sp_executesql @MyVariable ?? @MyVariable stores for instance a query like this: SELECT ROWGUID FROM MySimpleTable

Comment: How can I use "exec sp_executesql @MyVariable " inside this CTE?

Comment: The CTE will now store everything that is in your Variable.

Comment: but I have to use variable. I don't know what kind of sql query will be generated and included in Variable. I only know what kind of field from what kind of column will be returned

Answer (score 3):

> Keep it simple

```
-- Your original declaration
declare @myVariable nvarchar(max)
set @myVariable = 'Select ROWGUID from MySampleTable'

-- Additional code
declare @myQuery nvarchar(max) = 'SELECT ROWGUID FROM myTable WHERE ROWGUID in (' + @myVariable + ')'

exec (@myQuery)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could use [User Defined Functions](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/user-defined-functions) instead of stored procedures?